# Automapper, unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, automapper

For the first time I'm using Automapper and I'm facing with this problem:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
> Mapping types:
> History -> History_Archive
> My.Project.Trace.History -> My.Project.Trace.Trace.History_Archive
> Destination path:
> MyObj_Archive.Hystories.Hystories.Hystories0[0]

Here are my models:

```
public class MyObj
{
   ..props..

        [DataMember]
        public virtual IList<History> Hystories{get;set;}
    
  ..props..
}

public class MyObj_Archive
{
   ..props..

        [DataMember]
        public virtual IList<History_Archive> Hystories{get;set;}
    
  ..props..
}
```

the properties in History and History_Archive are the same.

Here is the configurations for Automapper:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
   Mapper.Configuration.CreateMap<MyObj, MyObj_Archive>()
      .ForMember(r => r.Hystories, opt => opt.MapFrom(r => r.Hystories))
      .ReverseMap();
}
```

I'm using.NET Framework 4 and AutoMapper 4.1.1

I know that theres many answers fot this problem but I haven't found a solution yet.
Any suggestions please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to create a map for History and History_Archive:
`CreateMap<History, History_Archive>().ReverseMap();`